# center image in canvas html

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to center an svg image in canvas, however the image goes to the right bottom corner, I couldn't understand what I'm doing wrong.

notice: the image is an svg image, I tried a png image it works, however an svg image start the problem.

this is the code I tried

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
     const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
     const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     const CANVAS_WIDTH = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 100);
     const CANVAS_HEIGHT = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 100);

     class Game {
          constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
               this.width = gameWidth;
               this.height = gameHeight;
               this.image = new Image();
               this.image.src = option.introImage;
               this.centerX = this.width / 2;
               this.centerY = this.height / 2;

               this.x = this.centerX - this.image.width * 0.5;
               this.y = this.centerY - this.image.height * 0.5;
          }

          draw(context) {
               context.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y);
          }

          update() {}
     }

     const game = new Game(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

     function animate() {
          game.update();
          game.draw(context);
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     }
     animate();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue with your code may be the timing of the image loading and the calculation of its position. When you calculate `this.x` and `this.y` in the constructor of your Game class, the image might not have loaded yet, so `this.image.width` and `this.image.height` are likely still 0. This means that `this.x` and `this.y` are being set to the center of the canvas, which is why the image appears in the bottom right corner once it loads and gets its actual size.

Comment: yeh but the draw image it keeps executing, so i think whenever the this.x and this.y are ready they will be updated

Comment: @walidnaceri you said: `the this.x and this.y are ready they will be updated` your code does not shows that... like @sooshyan mentioned the x and y are calculated in the constructor